# mysql on Mac osx 10.10 stops automatically and wont restart

Tags: mysql, macos

I have had to reinstall my Macbook.
Now i am trying to reinstall apche, php and mysql following this guide:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

everything works fine, just the mysql...
after installing, the mysql stops automatically.
When i try to restart (in preferences or terminal) it won't start.
When i restart my Macbook, the mysql starts normally, but stops after some minutes and i cant restart it...

whats wrong? how do i fix this...

Comment: macosx native sql or brew's version?

Comment: sorry, dont know what brew is. i downloaded mysql from the main page and installed it.

Comment: still need help plz....